# Where can I complain about Google Store target API level restrictions

Tags: android, google-play, android-api-levels

Google recently announced that they are going to start restricting publishing Android apps that do not target recent API level versions.  I support this change, but I need some special case exceptions, and have not found an appropriate forum to request those.  I know that this is not it, but hope someone here can point me where I should go.

I publish an app that has been out for a long time and still has a significant number of users running it under Gingerbread.  It also uses a number of support libraries, and the recent versions of those libraries, the ones targeting the latest API levels, no longer support Gingerbread devices.  The end result is that I can not build and apk that supports API level 9 if it targets an SDK level greater than 23.  Which is not going to be accepted come November.

I did have a plan to address this issue.  That was to start distributing two apk files for each update.  One that targets the latest API level and has a min API of probably 21.  The other will support older devices and will have a target and max API of 20 and a min API of 9.  The problem is that the older target API apk will not be accepted by the Play Store unless I can convince someone that they should continue to accept any app where the target and max API levels are the same.

Comment: While you make excellent points, [questions about app store policies are off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) and recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic. My guess is that you will need to use the higher `targetSdkVersion` even for the older support libraries. You can add the `//noinspection GradleCompatible` comment to block the Lint warning that you get for having an older support library than the `targetSdkVersion`. And then pray that it holds up.

Comment: FWIW, I [wrote up some other options](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/08/android-version-ratchet.html) that you could consider for addressing the issue.

Comment: Have you got that platform or page where we can share our experience or give some feedback about new release or updates

Answer (score 0):

Google is not stopping with these restriction, and one of their goals is to kill old apps and old devices.

My recommendation to you as a walk a round:

- Target the API required by Google
- Make two versions of the app
- The `1st version` is an empty app that have min SDK (API level 9) and Target the highest API level. this app will Point the users to a link of the APK (self hosted APK  will call it `1st ALt version`) Try to explain to the users that they need to do this because their devices are older (This self hosted APK should have a very high build code, so if `1st version` have build code of `9` the `1st ALt version` build code should be something like `1009` and should be signed with the same keystore so the `1st ALt version` will be updating the `1st version`)
- Then release a new version of your full app that does not support older API levels, we will call it The `2nd version`
- release the `2nd version` with rollout of 99.99999%
- this way all users from Google Play will download the `2nd version` except the users whom have older devices